Issue with @ManyToOne Lazy Loading: Unable to Find Entity by ID
Edit
I added an attribute that can be the problem, it had the same column name in the yEntity and the xEntity, but he is not part of the relationship (the Integer yEntity in yEntity who is a reference to another object (same class) ).
Moreover
In the debbug i get this error when i'm try to check the xEntity
Method threw 'org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException' exception. Cannot evaluate fr.gouv.isidor.importation.infra.database.entity.themes.ThemeGroupeEntity$HibernateProxy$eChsTNoK.toString()
Main problem
I'm encountering an issue with lazy loading in my Spring Boot application. When I use FetchType.LAZY on a @ManyToOne relationship, I'm unable to fetch the associated entity, and I get an error indicating that the entity with a specific ID cannot be found. However, when I switch to FetchType.EAGER, the problem disappears in the part of the code where I'm currently working, but it breaks another previously implemented section, causing the same error.
Entities
Here are the two entities involved in this relationship:
XEntity

@Entity
@Table(name = "x")
public class xEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nom", nullable = false)
    private String nom;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_y", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private yEntity yEntity;

    // Getters and setters
}


yEntity
@Table(name = "y")
public class yEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "theme_groupe_id_generator_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "theme_groupe_id_generator_seq", sequenceName = "theme_groupe_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "yEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<xEntity> themes;

    @Column(name="id_y")
    private Integer yEntity;

    // Getters and setters
}

Problem Description
When I try to access the yEntity from xEntity with FetchType.LAZY, I get the following error:
Unable to find fr.gouv.isidor.importation.infra.database.entity.themes.ThemeGroupeEntity with id 4
What I've Tried

Ensuring the session is open using @Transactional on every method that call the repository.
Using Hibernate.initialize() to force initialization. Verified that the
entity with the given ID exists in the database.
Tried with FetchType.EAGER, which works in the current part of the code but
causes the same issue in another section (in this case the code works with LAZY and doesn't with EAGER).

For calling the xEntity in the first case (who are working with EAGER and doesn't with LAZY) i'm using native jpa findById(Integer id).
For calling the xEntity in the second case (who art workin with LAZY and doesn't with EAGER) i'm using nativ jpa findByName(String name).
How can I properly configure lazy loading for the ThemeGroupeEntity association in ThemeEntity to avoid this error? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

not fully sure about it, but it feels a bit awkward that xEntity is the owner of the relation, but you have CascadeTypes and orphanRemoval on the other side of the relation. Have you tried removing the mappedBy on the themes side and adding it in the xEntity side?

I can't put the mappedBy on the ManyToOne annotation. At the start, i didn't have the OneToMany annotation and attribute on this side, i had nothing, it was a test to try to correct the error, adding it doesn't help...

In your case, fetch join and @EntityGraph could be good choices.
Using fetch join allows you to load associated entities together, even in cases of LAZY loading, when necessary.
public interface XEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<XEntity, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT x FROM XEntity x JOIN FETCH x.yEntity WHERE x.id = :id")
    Optional<XEntity> findByIdWithYEntity(@Param("id") Long id);
}

Adding a fetch join query to your repository method can resolve it.

While fetch join is a good approach, the @EntityGraph annotation provided by Spring can be an even more convenient option.
Using @EntityGraph allows you to use JPA instead of having to use JPQL to employ fetch joins.
Entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "x")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "xEntity.withYEntity", 
    attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("yEntity"))
public class xEntity {
    ...
}

Repository
public interface XEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<xEntity, Long> {
    @EntityGraph(value = "xEntity.withYEntity", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    Optional<xEntity> findById(Long id);

    @EntityGraph(value = "xEntity.withYEntity", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    xEntity findByNom(String nom);
}


Ok, thanks. I'll try using the EntityGraph. As for the join entity, that was my solution to fix the bug. I thought it wasn't good practice, but it was a temporary fix for me.

Good luck!
If you encounter any issues, please let me know in the comments.
